# Declare workbook as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to declare a workbook location as a variable so I do not have to change the name in 100 locations. The block of code is copied multiple times only the destination changes

```
Sub copyToDatabase_2()
'
' Copy from seperator to DB
'
    Dim location_1 As Workbooks
    Dim location_2 As Workbooks


    location_1 = "Table Separator (M2).xlsm"
    location_2 = "TCE-525 (M2) DAVID.xlsm"

    Windows(location_1).Activate
    Range("A5:E16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(location_2).Activate
    Range("R3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Windows(location_1).Activate
    Range("A19:E30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(location_2).Activate
    Range("R35").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

error received is

> Compile error: Invalid use of property.

Comment: Sorry I am newish to Excel VBA, online courses only

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). That should help you avoid using `Select` and `Activate` and also how to reference each workbook.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a string to a `Workbooks` variable:

```
Dim location_1 As Workbooks
' ...

location_1 = "Table Separator (M2).xlsm"
```

A quick fix would be define the variables as `String`, but you ought to apply the suggestions in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), as @BigBen noted.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly in combo with BigBen

Comment: @dcole204 feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left, glad your issue is resolved.